# Undefined index: image - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I try to modify a line in my table without touching the image because I already have an image in my database, but when I update, it shows me this error :

```
ErrorException
Undefined index: image
```

ProductController.php

```
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {

        $inputs = $request->except('_token', '_method');
        $path = basename($inputs['image']->store('public/img/products'));
        $product = Product::find($id);
        foreach ($inputs as $key => $value) {
            $product->$key = $value;
        }
        $product->image=$path;
        $product->save();
        return redirect('admin/gamelist');
    }
```

edit.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group d-flex flex-column">
        <label for="image">Image</label>
    <input type="file" name="image" id="image" value="{{$product->image}}">
</div>
```

Can someone help me? thank you

Comment: I think files are not listed with the other attributes in your `$request`. Try using `$request->file('image')` instead. https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files

Comment: Okay thank you, i'll try to do it using this method